# Apache status suddenly stops

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, lamp

I have a problem with my apache, I am running Ubuntu server 12.04 on a VPS. I have a basic LAMP stack, my problem is this, every few days apache will just stop and I will just notice this if I checked my blog. I don't have any problems like this before, I was using apache 2.2 before and currently I have apache 2.4.

I already reinstalled apache and I thought everything was okay, but right now it just happened again and my website was down, I don't know how long it was til I noticed that apache had stopped.

Any suggestion that could help me sort this thing out? Thank you very much

LAMP Information:
Apache 2.4.9
PHP 5.5.14
MySQL 5.5

Comment: Could you post any relevant parts of `error_log`?

Comment: Hello, are you referring to the apache error log? Here it is, do you thinkg it has something to do with line number 4 on this pastebin? http://pastebin.com/nSMZk6Fj I am just new in maintaining a VPS, thank you.

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/588748/glibc-detected-usr-sbin-httpd-free-invalid-pointer)

Comment: Thanks for the link Letizia, but I don't use APC on my VPS, I am currently using Zend Opcache. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution could be a string in /etc/crontab to restart apache each hour, for example.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
```

This will restart apache each 5 minutes.

But of course, we would like to know the reason it stops, right? There could be a lot of different reasons, as long as you have VPS.

Your provider could just use some kind of limiting system, which kills processes, which use too much of CPU or memory. Are you sure about apache quiting? Could you show the result of `sudo netstat -tanp` command, when apache stops?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am pretty sure that it is the apache which is quitting, because I need to start it once it occurred, however I could not provide the result of netstat yet because I have to wait for it to happen again or will the result be the same if I run it right now? Thanks

Comment: Well, right now netstat will not be very useful. Just wait for apache to quit and try do a netstat then.

Comment: Thanks for that then, is it okay to leave this topic open til I get back here?

Comment: Of course you can leave it still open :)